# Android MediaPlayer not playing wav file from raw folder (Android Lollipop)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to play wav file from raw folder using MediaPlayer, on all android versions(4.0-4.4.4) it is working, but on Android L preview(and on Android Lollipop AOSP build) there is no sound, and no error.
Here is my code:

```
mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(GlobalParameters.mContext, R.raw.beep);
mPlayer.start();

mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.reset();
            mPlayer.release();
        }

    }
 });
```

Comment: Just checked it on official android lollipop, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

How long is the sound effect you are trying to play?

In my experience, i could not get any .wav files that were shorter than 0.2s to produce sound on Lollipop, where in other versions, 4.0 - 4.4.4, they played fine. I got around this by using Audacity (or some other audio manipulation tool) to pad the end of the sound effect with silence. Once they were >= 0.2s, they played on Lollipop with no problem.

I do not know if that is your problem, but you might want to give it a shot.

Answer (score -1):

There is a reported issue here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77860

```
Reported by h6a.h4...@gmail.com, Oct 21, 2014
Description:

I noticed MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener callback behavior seems to be changed since Lollipop.


[KitKat]

- setLooping(false), setNextMediaPlayer(null)
    -> onCompletion() is fired
- setLooping(true), setNextMediaPlayer(null)
    -> onCompletion() is not fired
- setLooping(false), setNextMediaPlayer(other valid instance)
    -> onCompletion() is not fired
- setLooping(true), setNextMediaPlayer(other valid instance)
    -> onCompletion() is not fired

[Lollipop (when using AwesomePlayer)]

- setLooping(false), setNextMediaPlayer(null)
    -> onCompletion() is fired  : OK
- setLooping(true), setNextMediaPlayer(null)
    -> onCompletion() is not fired  : OK
- setLooping(false), setNextMediaPlayer(other valid instance)
    -> onCompletion() is fired  : ???
- setLooping(true), setNextMediaPlayer(other valid instance)
    -> onCompletion() is not fired  : OK


[Lollipop (when using NuPlayer)]

- setLooping(false), setNextMediaPlayer(null)
    -> onCompletion() is fired  : OK
- setLooping(true), setNextMediaPlayer(null)
    -> onCompletion() is fired  : ???
- setLooping(false), setNextMediaPlayer(other valid instance)
    -> onCompletion() is fired  : ???
- setLooping(true), setNextMediaPlayer(other valid instance)
    -> onCompletion() is fired  : ???


Tested environment:

- Nexus 7 2013
- Android 5.0 (LPX13D)
    bugreport.txt.tar.gz 
740 KB   Download
Oct 22, 2014 Project Member #1 michaelb...@google.com
Thank you for reporting this issue. We have passed this on to the development team and will update this issue with more information as it becomes available.
Status: Accepted 
Owner: michaelb...@google.com 
Labels: 18080636
```